# How do I Run a Template.HTML file in Index.html?

Tags: html, npm

I downloaded this template: https://github.com/cobidev/simplefolio to create a personal website, and edited the template.html file within the src folder. How do I run the template.html file in index.html so I can deploy the index.html file? Copying the code into a new index.html file results just results in plain HTML without any animation.

Comment: What are you using to host all of this during testing? If you're accessing something beginning with `file:` rather than `http(s):`, then none of those Javascript links are going to run for security reasons.

Comment: Right now, I am hosting this on localhost:8080, which is running fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the page using iframe. but you can also check for the assets path in you index.html then no need to use iframe

```
<iframe src="template.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```